# Disable other check boxes with [disabled] in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I want the other check boxes to be disabled when one is selected. I am doing so by

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ssn" (change)="checkBox[0].checked=!checkBox[0].checked">
</span>

<span class="input-group-addon">
   <label>{{checkBox[0].label}}</label>
</span>

<input [(ngModel)]="ssn" type="password" name="ssnText" class="form-control" placeholder=" ">
```

I have 6 checkboxes all of which look like above. However I want them to only be able to select 1 checkbox NOT multiple like it is doing right now.

In my component:

```
ssn:string;
    userId:string;
    lastName:string;
    office:string;
    role:string;

checkIfOthersAreSelected:boolean

checkBox = [
    {label: 'SSN', name:'ssn', checked:false},
    {label: 'Last Name', name:'lastName', checked:false},
    {label: 'Role', name:'role', checked:false},
    {label: 'UserId', name:'userId', checked:false},
    {label: 'Office', name:'office', checked:false},
    {label: ' Include Subordinates', name:'subordinates', checked:false}
];
```

button in html

```
<button type="submit" (click)="search(checkBox)" class="btn btn-default btn-md left-button">Search</button>
```

searchMethod

```
 public search(checkboxArray) {

        let ssn = checkboxArray[0];
        let lastName=checkboxArray[1];
        let role=checkboxArray[2];
        let userId= checkboxArray[3];
        let office=checkboxArray[4];


        if(ssn.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+ssn.name+" input: "+this.ssn);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserBySSN(this.ssn);
        }
        if(userId.checked == true){
            console.log("What is checked: "+userId.name+" input: "+this.userId);
            this.user = this._searchService.getUserById(this.userId);
        }
```

Comment: event is not boolean. Try as first row in your checkSelected handler to put console.log(event). This way you will be able to inspect the object properties.

Comment: Are these checkboxes iterated in ngFor or?

Comment: @AJT_82 no these are not in `*ngFor`  I have updated my code.

Comment: @NikolaYankov I have updated my code. Still have the same issue.

Comment: @AJT_82 I issued a bounty

Comment: @NikolaYankov I issued a bounty

Comment: @Drew1208  Would it be impossible to use radio buttons? Would make your life easier ;) But I'll take a look and see if I can come up with something!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it. Of course you could also do this with iteration if you like, but since you have all the checkbox separately I will do that here. Let's create a new method `checkSelected` that takes the label of the checkbox value which is triggered by `(change)` event. We set disable for checkboxes when the `checked` is set as true

```
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="checkBox[0].checked" (change)="checkSelected(checkBox[0].label)">{{checkBox[0].label}}
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="checkBox[1].checked" (change)="checkSelected(checkBox[1].label)">{{checkBox[1].label}}
<!-- The rest of the checkboxes -->
```

And in your TS let's iterate the array and check which label matches the one chosen. For the other checkboxes, we'll toggle the boolean value `checked` to true, while the chosen checkbox remains false.

```
checkSelected(label: string) {
   this.checkBox.forEach(x => {
       if(x.label !== label) {
           x.checked = !x.checked
       }
   })
}
```

When you uncheck the checkbox, it still remains false, and the other ones become false as well!

And there ya go, all done! :) Here's a **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lO9AniJLYMQsNk3KlaAA?p=preview)**.

Comment: This worked BUT my function doesn't know which checkbox is selected. Please see my updated post. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: This worked BUT my function doesn't know which checkbox is selected. Please see my updated post. Thank you for your efforts. Now the one that is selected is the only one that doesn't print out in the console.

Comment: I just changed the values in the method and it works, thank you

Comment: Okay great! Yeah, you need to search for the checkbox value that is false. Seems a bit backwards perhaps, but I utilized the boolean value you had set in your array, but it maybe feels a bit weird to search for the value that is false :)

Comment: I really wish I could have used radio buttons. Do you happen to know a way I can use your method but with radio buttons? If I make it a radio button I cannot deselect it. Very annoying... I want the user to be able to check a radio of checkbox and it unchecks the others. This way you have to uncheck it to open the others.

Comment: If you use radio button you can use one additional labeled "none of the above", so you have one extra.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
<input type="checkbox" [disabled]="checkIfOthersAreSelected" (change)="checkSelected($event)" />
```

In your event

```
checkSelected(e) {

   if(e.target.checked){
        this.checkIfOthersAreSelected = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it'S a case for radio buttons instead of check boxes. And in this case I'm using [this radio buttons from @angular/material](https://material.angular.io/components/component/radio). The setup of materials is a little bit challenging, but the components are worth it.

Comment: Looks great but not a lot of examples and my project doesn't recognize the HTML tags and I have `ReactiveFormsModule` imported

Comment: Oh, the `ReactiveFormsModule` is still on my list to learn. The html tags needs to be setup see the [getting started](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Answer (score 1):

```
Enable disable textbox based on checkbox check event.

<input type="checkbox" 
[checked]="employee.PhysicalyChalanged" 
[(ngModel)]="employee.PhysicalyChalanged" 
id="PhysicalyChalanged" 
#PhysicalyChalanged
name="PhysicalyChalanged">

<input type="number" 
placeholder="Enter Physicaly Chalanged Percentage" 
class="form-control" 
id="PhysicalyChalangedPercentage" 
maxlength="3"
[disabled]="!PhysicalyChalanged.checked"
[(ngModel)]="employee.PhysicalyChalangedPercentage" 
name="PhysicalyChalangedPercentage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a radio button group instead? That functionality can be achieved without the use of any JavaScript (if I understand your needs correctly).

[Take a look at radio buttons](http://www.echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm)

Comment: I tried that too but once you select the radio button you cannot deselect it. I have been fighting with this for a while now. It would be so much easier if I could use `*ngFor` but I cannot in this case.

Comment: As stated above: add an extra radio button labeled "none of the above", then this is your deselect.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying a `<select>` dropdown list with a 'none' option, which allows the user to effectively clear their selected search item?

```html
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option value='---'>None</option>
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" name='{{option.name}}'>{{option.label}}</option>
</select>
```

```js
ssn:string;
userId:string;
lastName:string;
office:string;
role:string;

options = [
    {label: 'SSN', name:'ssn', checked:false},
    {label: 'Last Name', name:'lastName', checked:false},
    {label: 'Role', name:'role', checked:false},
    {label: 'UserId', name:'userId', checked:false},
    {label: 'Office', name:'office', checked:false},
    {label: ' Include Subordinates', name:'subordinates', checked:false}
];

onChange(optionValue) {
    if(optionValue === '---') {
       // clear your search query
    } else {
       // do your search
    }
}
```