# angular 5 array Cannot read property ' ' of undefined

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a form with several divs that have a label - checkbox - input. 
when you open the menu every checkbox are unchecked which means every input is disabled and then you decide which one you want to fill in which you do by checking the checkbox and enabling the input.

So, I followed [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305695/disable-other-check-boxes-with-disabled-in-angular-2) but I get an error of undefined on the array. The first checkbox (index [0]) always works, but the subsequent objects dont.

This is how it looks.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.resetValues();
    ..........
    ......
    ...
}
    
resetValues() {
    this.checkboxArr = [
        { name: 'disabledDegree', disabled: true },
        { name: 'disabledEmployedTo', disabled: true },
        { name: 'disabledEmploymentType', disabled: true },
        { name: 'disabledSelOrg', disabled: true },
        { name: 'disabledSelMan', disabled: true }
    ];
    .......
    .....
    ..
}
    
checkSelected(name: string) {
    console.log('name', name);
    this.checkboxArr.forEach((x: any) => {
        if (x.name === name) {
            x.disabled = !x.disabled;
        }
    });
    console.log('loop', this.checkboxArr);
}
```

```html
<div class="inner" *ngIf="checkboxArr && checkboxArr.length"> <-- adding this ngIf did nothing.
<div class="row">
    <div class="label-column">
        <label for="DegreeOfEmployment">...</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="DegreeOfEmploymentCheckBox" name="DegreeOfEmploymentCheckBox" (change)="checkSelected(checkboxArr[0].name)">
    </div>
    <div class="input-column target-org-unit">
        <input [disabled]="checkboxArr[0].disabled" id="DegreeOfEmployment" name="DegreeOfEmployment" type="text" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="label-column">
        <label for="EmployedTo">....</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="EmployedToCheckBox" name="EmployedToCheckBox" (change)="checkSelected(checkBoxArr[1].name)">
        </div>
        <div class="input-column target-org-unit">
            <input [disabled]="checkBoxArr[1].disabled"  id="EmployedTo" name="EmployedTo" type="date" value="">                            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="label-column">
            <label for="EmploymentType">....</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="EmploymentTypeCheckBox" name="EmploymentTypeCheckBox" (change)="checkSelected(checkBoxArr[2].name)">
        </div>
        <div class="input-column target-org-unit">
            <input [disabled]="checkBoxArr[2].disabled" id="EmploymentType" name="EmploymentType" type="text" value="">                            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). (Your current Stack Snippet isn't **runnable**. If it's not going to be runnable, just use code blocks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular/JavaScript/TypeScript is case sensetive even if HTML is not. Either use `checkBoxArr` or `checkboxArr`. Don't mix it neither in your ts/js nor in your html files.

Comment: Jesus, thats awkward... That was it. Thanks alot!